# HTML INPUT tag not inheriting CSS from FORM

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

I have some HTML forms. I am using tables. I am superimposing png's over submit buttons.

In example A, the CSS below works. In example B it does not. I have checked the CSS debugger, and the issue seems to be that the INPUT field does not inherit from FORM, when it is separated from it by the TR or TD tags. Presumably there should be a way to statically redefine this inheritance in CSS.  Can anybody point me at the correct solution?

The use of tables is a constraint in this particular case.

EXAMPLE A:

```html
<TABLE class="navbutton">
<TR class="navbutton"><TD class="navbutton">
   <form method="post" action="/AdminPalette" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
   <input type="submit" name="add" value="add" class="add" />
</TD><TR>
</form>
```

EXAMPLE B:

```html
<TABLE class="navbutton">
   <form method="post" action="/AdminPalette" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<TR class="navbutton"><TD class="navbutton">
   <input type="submit" name="add" value="add" class="add" />
</TD><TR>
</form>
```

EXAMPLE CSS:

```css
form input[type=submit].add {
 width : 32px;
 height :32px;
 border : none;
 color : transparent;
 font-size : 0;
        cursor: pointer;
}

form input[type=submit].add {
 background : url("/Art/GCON/green/add-item.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Put your form tag either around the table, or inside one cell. You can't start it as a child of the table or cell, and end it outside the table.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with inheritance.

Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

A table can be contained with in a form. A form can be contained within a table cell. A form cannot be a child element of a table (or of a table row, table body, table header or table footer).

Your browser is error correcting by putting the form after the table (but leaving the inputs behind).